# Tooltips are not shown in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In this website: http://www.blackblot.co.il/kb/ I can't make the anchor ( tags) to show tooltips in IE.
It works in chrome and Firefox. 
what makes it even harder to understand, is it not happenening in all the tags, but only these in the content section. 
for example, the links on the left side are showing the titles, but the links in the content, altough has it, won't show it.
I checked for CSS manipulation, or js code, but nothing really stops it from showing the titles.

really need help here. Thanks

Comment: Any chance of a hidden element overlaying that section?  I seem to remember running into trouble with something like that in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK
I found the solution. which is not a real solution - but it something in IE was absolutely wrong.
it is clearly a bug in IE. Anyway, if someone have the same problem.
I have dicided to take off the css and see if I see the tooltips without any css. And then I saw it.

So I had to debug 500 lines of poorly written CSS. Among these 500 line there were 3 declarations that caused this bug. I found that when I use F12 (developer's tools of IE) the positioning of the element was not in it's actual position on the page. Please see image attached.

So I tried to figure out which css declaration causing this. For some reason 3 declaration of 3 div's padding had to be removed in order for this to work.

the CSS lines are as follow, the commented code is the bad guy:

```
ul,ol,dl,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; /* padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0; */} 
div.post,div.page{display:block; margin:0 0 0px 0; border-bottom:solid 1px #eee; /* padding:20px */}
div.post-bodycopy p{margin:1em 0; /* padding:0; */ display:block; font-size: 13px;}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can post the actual code instead of a picture of the code we cannot see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the source code and found out that the anchors didn't have titles. Did you try putting titles in those anchors? That should work in my opinion.

Comment: There is a title in the tags. for example the link that says: (Product Manager's Toolkit® (PMTK